# SQL Server: Raiserror where @variable = true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiseerror

I can't seem to work this out. I want to kill my script if a variable is true. but I can't find any answers so far.

What I'm trying:

```
raiserror('Error', 18, -1)
Where @Variable='True';
```

I have declared and assigned the variable already

Comment: `RAISERROR` is not a `SELECT`. The syntax is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql). You can't stick arbitrary `WHERE` clauses on statements, but you can use [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql).

Answer (score 4):

`raiseerror` is a T-SQL command. It doesn't have a `where` clause, but you could put it inside an `if` block:

```
IF @Variable = 'True'
    raiserror('Error', 18, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use it like sql query. It is command so you can write as

```
IF @Variable = 'True'
BEGIN
    raiserror('Error', 18, -1);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are correct about the structure of the conditional check, but I will recommend that you use `THROW` rather than `RAISERROR`, based on documentation. Microsoft's documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
IF @Variable = 'True'
BEGIN
   THROW 50000, 'Error', 1;
END
```

And, as an aside, you should strongly consider not using text literals like 'true' or 'false' in your code and instead opt for the `BIT` datatype to achieve the same, where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I want to counter-propose the advice of paneerakbari here.

Sure, Microsoft documentation recommends using `throw` instead of raiserror.

However, Erland Sommarskog, a Microsoft MVP with a blog that consists of very enlightened posts, discusses in [Part 2 of his Error and Transaction Handling article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#THROW) that `THROW` does less stuff that raiserror, it requires a semicolon which might be perilously forgotten. I thus strongly recommend sticking to the less dangerous `raiserror`.